# How do I setup wireless on HP nc8430?

Tags: hp, compaq

How do I setup or enable wireless on a HP Compaq nc8430 laptop?  And is there a recommended list of software updates for an nc8430?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look on the HP website for drivers and then goto System Settings>Networking>Wireless. Here is the url for the website: http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html